# C# remove last dynamically created textbox

Tags: c#

Almost totally noob here. Im stucked. I know how to delete all dc textboxes but have no idea how to delete only last created one. Thx

piece of my code:

```
int B = 1;
    public void NovIntRazd()
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        this.Controls.Add(txt);
        txt.Top = B * 30;
        txt.Left = 26;
        txt.Height = 20;
        txt.Width = 65;
        txt.Name = "txtIntRazd" + this.B.ToString();
        B++;
    }
```

Comment: The quick and dirty way is to move your `TextBox txt` outside of `NovIntRazd`.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem, or at least isn't telling us the whole requirement. If you only want to remove the last item, and only once, then @GSerg is correct, but if you want to keep removing them, you're going to need to store them in a list.

Comment: You can do something like `Controls.OfType<TextBox>().OrderByDesc(a => a.Top).FirstOrDefault()`, which will get you the last `TextBox` that you can remove from the collection then. This will work repeatedly. Saving the last element will not (without finding the next last one). Don't forget to `--B` after removing the item.

Comment: Yes, the idea was that i can keep removing them if i want by pressing button. Didnt remember to put them in the list. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to ever remove one textbox, you can just keep the reference to the last one:

```
int B = 1;
TextBox txt;
public void NovIntRazd()
{
    txt = new TextBox();
    this.Controls.Add(txt);
    txt.Top = B * 30;
    txt.Left = 26;
    txt.Height = 20;
    txt.Width = 65;
    txt.Name = "txtIntRazd" + this.B.ToString();
    B++;
}

public void RemoveLast()
{
    if (txt == null) return;
    Controls.Remove(txt);
    txt = null;
}
```

Alternatively, a good practice is to put dynamically created controls in their own container, like a panel. It sounds like your case is a perfect use for a `FlowLayoutPanel`, which will handle control positioning too. When you remove any control, all the others are automatically moved around to the right places.

Then to remove the last added control, you can just do

```
if (pnl.Controls.Count > 0) pnl.Controls.RemoveAt(pnl.Controls.Count - 1);
```

If you really want to keep the controls mixed up in the top-level form, you can easily organize the dynamic textboxes by using a `Stack`:

```
Stack<TextBox> textboxes = new Stack<TextBox>();

public void NovIntRazd()
{
    var txt = new TextBox()
       {
         Top = (textboxes.Count + 1) * 30, 
         Left = 26,
         Height = 20,
         Width = 65,
         Name = "txtIntRazd" + (textboxes.Count + 1).ToString()
       };

    this.Controls.Add(txt);
    textboxes.Push(txt);
}

public void RemoveLast()
{
    if (textboxes.Count == 0) return;
    Controls.Remove(textboxes.Pop());
}
```

Comment: Hi. Didnt know that exists FlowLayoutPanel, so thaaank you. Probably this will be best solution. And of course first solution with reference works fine. Thx again.